In spark execution does really each stages are depended to its previous stage?
Each time data shuffling results in a new stage, each new stage depends on its previous stage. In that case, the execution of stages will be in sequential order not parallel but the task within the stage can be executed parallelly.
NOTE- Please correct me if I am on the wrong page.
Just trying to understand the concept.

this is not a correct understanding. Spark stages can run in parallel as well sequentially depending on need. You can find more about this on official spark documentation page.
It has both examples where execution is sequential and parallel.
This is well explained there.
https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/what-is-spark-stage/

Hi Nikhil,
Thank you for your support. I noticed an error in the given link explanation of Example 1.
The job described-
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
RDD filter
val filtered = data.filter(_ % 2 == 0)
val mapped = filtered.map(_ * 2)
val result = mapped.collect()
It mentions three stages:
Creating the RDD using parallelize.
Filtering data using filter.
Mapping data using map.
This is incorrect. Since there are no wide transformations (shuffling) and only narrow transformations (filter and map), there should be a single stage.

Yes you are correct, I think you are confusing between stage and task, a stage can have multiple task and in example 1 there are 3 tasks and 1 stage. Whatever you write spark will create task for it and optimise the task and stages as per it for better performance
